# Python: Download zip file from RestAPI

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

Third party RestAPI provides server log file, at a moment we are downloading  log file using curl command like

```
curl -H "X-Auth-Token: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" https://host_address/api/v3.0/admin/logs -o logs.zip
```

but I am trying to create simple dashboard using Flask/Python,

Here is my Python/Flask code for the route:

```
@app.route('/download/server/logs')
def download_log():
    import requests
    from flask import send_file
    res = requests.get('http://<rest_api_host>/v1.2/admin/logs', stream=True)
    return send_file(
        res.content,
        attachment_filename='console_log.zip',
        mimetype='application/zip'
    )
```

But when I hit that url from browser I get below error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
...
...
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/project/__init__.py", line 940, in download_console_logs
    res.content,
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/project/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 823, in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/project/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 745, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/project/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 436, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/project/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 384, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 449, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 497, in readinto
    self._close_conn()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 403, in _close_conn
    fp.close()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

I put the breakpoint/debugger using PyCharm and able to see that `res.content` contains binary data in it, but I'm not able to figure it out what is wrong here.

Here is the simple diagram which explains what I'm trying to do,
[image]

**UPDATE: ANSWER:** I took below approach and it solves my problem in a very efficient way.

```
@app.route('/download/server/logs')
def download_log():
    import requests
    from flask import Reponse
    res = requests.get('http://<rest_api_host>/v1.2/admin/logs', stream=True)
    return Response(
        res.iter_content(chunk_size=1024),
        direct_passthrough=True
    )
```

Comment: You have an extra comma?

`from flask import, send_file`

Comment: @AdriVelaz thanks, that's typo while posting here

Comment: Hi, what happened with your problem? How is it going?

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal Thank you for your help, I solved it in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Download from local folder

```
def download_Object():
    try:
        srcFileName="bulk_file.zip"
        with open(srcFileName, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(srcFileName)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    srcFileName="filename"
    with open(srcFileName, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(srcFileName)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you have given the right error message. But I think it will not work given that you are passing a string to the `send_file()` method. You need to pass binary data instead.

If you wrap `res.content` inside `io.BytesIO()` and pass it to the `send_file()` method, I believe it should work.

Ex:

```
@app.route('/download/server/logs')
def download_log():
    import requests
    from flask import send_file
    import io
    res = requests.get('http://<rest_api_host>/v1.2/admin/logs', stream=True)
    return send_file(
        io.BytesIO(res.content),
        attachment_filename='console_log.zip',
        mimetype='application/zip'
    )
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: @n33rma what's the error message you get after adding this? and can you tell me how you run this app?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download the file try Response method of the flask :

```
import requests
from flask import Response
@app.route('/download/server/logs')
def download_log():
res = requests.get('http://<rest_api_host>/v1.2/admin/logs')
return Response(res.content,headers = dict(res.headers))
```